# Thank you for your Patience to a Teacher

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, word-usage, word-choice

I have a Korean teacher that is very nice and Patient with me especially, as I'm trying to learn. How do I say, "Thank you for your Patience"

I read this, but this seems more like a restaurant waiter/hostess speaking to customer.

기다려줘서 고마워

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a good student you are! But I don't know what your teacher patient for. So I suppose the situation your teacher patiently waiting until your speak ends.If I were you, I would like to say " 기다려주셔서(patiently waiting) 감사합니다(thank you)." Or another situation,  which your teacher patiently help you then "늘(always, patiently) 도움주셔서(help me) 감사합니다(thank you)."

In fact the above answer by user13229973 is expression very formally showing your respect and gratitude. You suggestion "기다려줘서 고마워" is quite rude expression even the situation in the restaurant. It is only allowed your close friend or girlfriend(boyfriend) .(ocassionally your wife(husband) )

Plus what makes the non-native korean speakers hard for learning Korean is korean language has two types. The first type is the words can be used for only really close relationships with you. Example for that, "고마워.(Thank you)" But the second type(polite expression) is the words used in not close relationship, your teacher, your parents or social activities . Example for that , "감사합니다."(Thank you for polite version). Korean people say the former thing 반말, latter thing 존댓말.

As korean, I hope your korean level progress more than ever.

Comment: hi , the first question recommendation wasn't my suggestion, something I read from another resource

Comment: @mattsmith5, Oh I see.  It looks like the resource you used does not suggest "존댓말" version.